# unix change number's value on given line number in shell script for loop

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, sed

How can I change a number on a line in a file using a unix tool like awk or sed?
I want to change the line 3 in my example file to the number 1-10 using a shell script. I think I need to use regex to recognize the digit but I'm not sure how to do this, or to allow multiple digits (like 10).

Example file:

```
/examples/are/hard so/hard/1
```

Shell script so far:

```
for i in {1..3};
do
sed 's|/examples/are/hard so/hard/7 | /examples/are/hard so/hard/'"$i" ex_file
cat ex_file
done
```

Desired output:

```
/examples/are/hard so/hard/1
/examples/are/hard so/hard/2
/examples/are/hard so/hard/3
```

Comment: Why are you running a loop and what's your expected output?

Comment: I'm using qsub to run batch scripts. I want to change the directory number qsub is sent to in each script. In this example, the expected result is the example file is left with a 10 instead of a 3.

Comment: I updated with a more concrete example.

Comment: Make your example correct. With an input file with value `10`, use `10` in your script. And delete the line `cat ex_file`.

Comment: This example was made to show a minimal representation of my problem with a concrete desired result. The reason cat is there is to show that the line should change each time. At your request, I changed the 10 to a 1.

Comment: Your question is still extremely unclear.  Perhaps the edit introduced some additional inconsistencies; either way, you need to think about how to explain your problem.  (Also, changing the example to run from 1 instead of 10 introduced another problem -- are you trying to get sequential numbering, or can the numbers start from an arbitrary offset?)  And finally, the problem seems rather trivial -- try to reduce it further (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then look for a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

What you've run isn't a valid sed command.  If you're trying to do a substitution, that's `s/search/replace/flags`.

I imagine you meant:

```
sed 's/here\/is the number\/to\/change 3/here\/is the number\/to\/change '"$i"'/' ex_file
```

Note that we temporarily break out of single quote.  Inside of single quotes, variable aren't interpolated.  We swap the double quotes, bring in `$i`, then return to single quotes to finish the command.

P.S. You also [don't have to](http://backreference.org/2010/02/20/using-different-delimiters-in-sed/) use `/` as your delimiter.

```
sed 's|here/is the number/to/change 3|here/is the number/to/change '"$i"'|' ex_file
```

Comment: Thanks! The hardwired 3 doesn't work for my case because the number will change during each loop iteration.

Comment: Yes it should.  The `$i` is outside of the double quotes, so it will be interpolated with each `for` iteration.

Comment: The `here\/is the number\/to\/change 3` statement hardwires 3 in.

Comment: Your example included `3`, so that's what I used.  What is it supposed to be?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. It's supposed to change from 1-10 through the loop. I was hoping there is a way to just recognize numeric terms (using regex?), but any solution would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of the desired output?  Are you trying to have it increment the value on each iteration, regardless of what the value originally was?  You could just match any number of digits in that position with `[0-9]*`

Comment: Yes I am. 10 is two characters, which I'm not sure how to handle with regex. I'll update my post for a more concrete expected outcome.